# Android twitpic application

Tags: android

I want to fetch the path where the images are stored in Emulator and use that path to share the photos in twitpic appliation can anyone please help with this sorry if I am not clear

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is the code to start the chooser activity

```
  Intent intent = new Intent();

  intent.setType("image/*");

  intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

  startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
```

On the result of this activity you can get the path of selected file from the following code

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {

            selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            anyImageButton.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
        }

    }

}

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

Hope this will help
:)

Comment: If the answer works for you then please accept it so that another can also get the right reference ... Hope it helps others too.. cheers

Comment: @Nehav there is a green tick mark beside the answer. If this answer worked for you press that